# Where did the "juices" in "creative juices" come from?

Tags: etymology, idioms

Where did the "juices" in "creative juices" come from?  Isn't that just a little weird? I don't think *juices* would be the first word to mind, if I hadn't heard the phrase before, and was free-associating metaphors to go with *creative*.  Is it a reference to the Aristotelean humors, maybe? That seems a bit far-fetched.  Or perhaps some really cool person coined the phrase and it stuck? Anyway, I'd just appreciate anyone giving me a plausible pathway on how it came to be a "stock phrase."

Comment: *The sap rising in spring*, *get the blood pumping*, *let the spirit flow*, etc., etc. The imagery of fluid movement is pretty standard symbolism throughout language. I'm fairly sure all life-forms depend on it too.

Comment: I always thought it was juices flowing a la *salivating*, i.e. one's mind is so happy to be working on something creative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=creative%20juices&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) of the term shows its birth as a "stock phrase" only dates back to the 1960s, but the words are found in print a century earlier and the first examples of the phrase being used to mean *[motivating, inspiring, or enabling forces or factors](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/juice)* go back to the 1930s. I'll give you one example of each.

I found *creative juices* in print back to this 1846 translation ([p. 182](http://books.google.com/books?id=FT8EAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=creative%20juices&f=false), scroll down) of *Kalevala*, a Finnish epic poem that recounts a mythical story of the cursed birth of steel:

[image: passage from p. 182]

I don't think this reference is incidental. The same section of this poem, with the same translation, was reprinted several times in the writings of [Lafcadio Hearn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lafcadio_Hearn) at the turn of the century and as late as [1922](http://books.google.com/books?id=txuGAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=creative%20juices&f=false). While not the figurative use of the phrase we have today, I think there's a good chance its occurrence in his writings led to its familiarity and adaptation in the 1930s.

The first use of it I could find in print with its modern connotation was from this 1936 article in *[The Delineator](http://books.google.com/books?id=nHZRAAAAYAAJ&q=%22creative%20juices%22&dq=%22creative%20juices%22&hl=en&ei=Ep6nTbHTCquy0QHdrs35CA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBQ)*:

> [...] and played and replayed and recorded and wrote down their early songs.
>   Their **creative juices** dried up. Only a
>   few of the original players stuck by
>   their guns, among them notably the men
>   mentioned in this article. They
>   continued, in honky-tonks, dives and
>   dance halls, to play as they felt and
>   feel as they played.

I wasn't able to get a more complete quote because of the limitations of Google's Snippet view, but it's clear the article is referring to the figurative *creative juices* of musicians.

One later 1930s reference of note is found in the intro to the 1939 [screenplay](http://books.google.com/books?ei=r6CnTcPZB-OH0QHGleX4CA&ct=result&id=PFaGAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22creative%20juices%22&q=creative%20juices#search_anchor) of Margaret Mitchell's *Gone with the Wind*.

Answer (score 6):

It could possibly have to do with the use of *juice* as a slang term for power or electricity. I found several quotes (all from the OED) that use *juice* in common circumstances when something is running or powered:

- **1896**:  “Now we know what a blessing the trolley is—when the *juice* isn't turned off.”—Boston Herald, 25 December, page 4/5
- **1908**: “Electric cars all stopped; no *juice*, no nothing, everything stopped.”—Saturday Evening Post, 18 July, page 10/2
- **1928**: "The *juice* was turned off, and Vanzetti was officially pronounced dead.”—Boston (1929) by Upton Sinclair, xxiv. page 724
- **1948**:  “Turn on the *juice* to this elevator, and do it now.”—Great Falls Tribune (Montana), 18 September, page 12/1
- **1997**: “Electric cars have a range of about 80 miles before they run out of *juice*.”—Daily News (Los Angeles), 9 October

Comment: +1 in French we have the same "Il n'y a plus de jus" (we're out of juice), "couper le jus" (cut the juice) and that goes even beyond electrical power. "Je n'ai plus de jus" (I'm running out of energy/stamina).

Answer (score 4):

*Juice* probably refers to *cerebrospinal fluid* around and inside the brain.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth.

In French you can hear "*Jus de crane*" (skull juice).
This attempts to convey the idea of "squeezing ideas" out of your brain.

I think that's close to the metaphor here: squeezing out creativity.

Same if you say "*Je suis sec, je sèche*..." ("I'm dry...").

Answer (score 1):

Creative is very new, in the literary sense, (Wordsworth C19) so it's just somebody being poetic (and creative)