# What does “I really get the juices flowing when I’m driving” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms, contemporary-english

The New York Times article “[In golf, moments good and bad are well remembered](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/06/16/sports/golf/in-golf-moments-good-and-bad-are-well-remembered.html?pagewanted=all)” (June 14) ends up with the following episode:

> Jerry Kelly (PGA golfer) said that his steely memory of golf extended to his personal life, especially when driving.
>
> > "I remember all those people who have cut me off," Kelly said. "I try to stay ahead of everybody so that I don’t let them cut me off again, especially when I come back to the Northeast. I really **get the juices flowing** when I’m driving here."

What does “get the juices flow” when driving mean? Does it mean to get the thrills and spills?

There’s no entry for “get the juices flow” in English dictionaries at hand, nor Google Ngram shows any incidence of the phrase.

Is this an idiom, or just a casual turn of phrase? If it’s a not-unusual phrase, in what else instances can I use “get the juices flow”?

**PS.**

Someone placed “This question may have an answer here -Where did the "juices" in "creative juices" come from? on top of my question. It doesn’t. I read through the said question, and find no connection / answer to mine. **My question has evidently nothing to do with “creative juice"** asked in that particular question.

My question is simply what Jerry Kelly meant in his remark, which now I wrapped my brain after posting this question, and getting a lot of inputs from you.

Comment: Well, there is http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_one's_juices_flowing. And http://www.italki.com/question/128529

Comment: As Andrew indirectly said, “get the juice flowing” is an uncommon way of saying it, at least to me. I would personally have said, “I really get _my juices_ flowing when I’m driving here” or even better, “Driving here really gets my juices flowing”.

Comment: And I see now, looking at the article, that ‘juices’ is indeed in the plural in the original.

Comment: Also see  [Where did the "juices" in "creative juices" come from?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/20976)

Comment: To the person who voted for close. Give me the answer first, then the reasons for having to close. NES can weigh whether the question is appropriate or stupid easily, because English is your mother language and ‘common sense.’ Unfortunately it doesn’t apply to us, non-native speakers. We don’t understand why question is closed or down-voted. It’s not a few times that I got a close / down vote at first on my question, which obtained 10 plus votes, sometimes 30 plus votes later.

Comment: Continued.Close vote and down vote without giving the manifest reason for it is to me the insidious action of muzzling. It just gives me de-ja vu of suppression of speech we suffered under military dictatorship before and during the WW II.

Comment: After writing the above comment, I came to realize this phrase could mean ‘urinate’ just as hindsight. If it is the case, is Jerry Kelley’s remark vulgar? And should we condemn New York Times for carrying his indecent remark, which tempted me to post the question?

Comment: @YoichiOishi Agreed; I don't see the justification for down-vote.

Comment: @YoichiOishi, it cannot possibly be taken to mean ‘urinate’. I mean, theoretically, it _could_—but that would be such an unusual and unidiomatic interpretation, that it would only work with the right context and probably with an explanation, too. For example, if the reporter had jokingly answered, “Oh dear! Well, I wouldn’t want to be the passenger in _your_ car, then: I’d be scared you’d pee on me!”, he would have known that she was deliberately turning the expression into something about urinating. But it is quite a far-fetched interpretation, not at all the immediate or natural one.

Comment: @YoichiOishi I think your indignation is, perhaps, uncalled for. There are two links posted which indicate the possible meanings of "juices flowing"; and somehow you wrote the singular form, juice, not once but twice in quotes (look at your title, which I hadn't noticed when I edited your question). I think your question deserves to stay open but please, don't think your freedom of speech is being attacked. That's going a *little* too far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where did the "juices" in "creative juices" come from?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20976/where-did-the-juices-in-creative-juices-come-from)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. Thanks for pointing out drop of 's' in juices in my question. I corrected. I'm particularly sloppy with singular/plural distinction as we don't have number (countable/uncountable) of noun in our language, and I was in naive understanding juice is uncountable because it is liquid.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I don’t think it was the downvote itself, but rather the (repeated) downvotes and close votes _with no explanations_. An insidious act of muzzling is perhaps a bit far to go, true, but I can understand why it is annoying. :-)

Comment: Well usually if it is a fruit juice it would be uncountable, but in this case we are talking about more than one type of bodily fluids (juices). So you weren't being naive at all, on the contrary you were thinking logically.

Comment: @RoryAlsop, I don’t think that is really a duplicate at all—especially because of the two related, but different, meanings of ‘juices’, this question looks for the other one; but also because that question deals only with what juices were originally referred to, as opposed to what the phrase really _implies_, semantically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘Juices’ is a kind of slangy term that means [‘a person’s vitality or creative faculties’](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/juice). The creative faculties are of course what is referenced in the expression mentioned in the question linked to by jwpat7 in the comment above; in this case, it’s the other meaning we’re looking for.

Since a person’s vitality is seen here as a kind of ‘juice’ (originally most likely referring on some level to bodily fluids: especially blood was, in Mediaeval times, often considered to be a source of energy, health, and vitality in humans), it makes sense that it should be set ‘flowing’, since that’s what liquids do.

This meaning is extended from the meaning [the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/101976?rskey=cZNBhm&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) has as sense 2:

> The fluid part or moisture of an animal body or substance; now usually in *pl.* the various liquid constituents of the body, the bodily ‘humours’

Obviously, if you think of it as being ultimately just a kind of euphemism for blood (and sweat and bile and all the other humours), getting it to flow, and flow faster especially, would be a sign of physical exertion or excitement: when we run, our blood actually flows faster, and our pulse increases.

The phrase is often also used in a sexual manner, where the reference is to the various kinds of sex-related bodily fluids that are released when people become aroused. Whether the sexual meaning came first or the exertion meaning came first (or whether they are really to be separated at all), I do not know; I cannot find any quotes for that. But it is clear that they are both in use.

In the quote from your NYT article, the meaning is definitely that of physical exertion–based excitement. He is comparing the ‘rush’ he gets from driving to a kind of race where he’s not going to let anyone pass him and be faster than him.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, 'get the juices flowing' means an increase in adrenaline and mental focus. 
In the context of creative thinking, the same phrase means fluidity of thought and mental focus.